# Find all the places where a block type is used

Tags: block-editor

I have a plugin installed that adds additional custom block types that can be used in the Gutenberg editor (the plugin is called Block Lab). Now I want to remove that plugin. For that, I have to remove all the used instances of those blocks. Is there a way to find all the occurrences of a used block type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that this is not welcome here, but my only answer is that I can refer you to the following plugin.

The plugin was released a few weeks ago and finds exactly the blocks used for your installation.

Exactly what you need.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/find-my-blocks/

Comment: Thank you so much, I just needed that. I was actually looking for such a plugin, but that was before its release ;)